# How do I remove the padding inside a div that has a propery of display and a value of inline-block

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the padding from inside of a div with the display set to "inline-block".

Below is the html and css.

```css
.showExpCusWrap {
  background-color: #A8D3FF;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #004F9D;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.showExpCusWrap label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.showExpCusWrap input[type="date"] {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="showExpCusWrap">
  <label for="showExpFrom">From</label>
  <input type="date" name="showExpFrom" id="showExpFrom">
  <label for="showExpTo">To</label>
  <input type="date" name="showExpTo" id="showExpTo">
  <input type="button" name="showExpCus" id="showExpCus" value="Show" class="exp-button-small">
</div>
```

This is how it looks. Notice the top and bottom padding inside.

[image: image1]

I have checked the broswer default styling. It does not set any padding. So, how to remove those? I want all the elements inside the div to appear without any spacing from top or bottom.

Answer (score 0):

While editing your question, I realized that there's no problem.

Here's a snippet of all the code that you sent.

```css
.showExpCusWrap {
  background-color: #A8D3FF;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #004F9D;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
.showExpCusWrap label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.showExpCusWrap input[type="date"]{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="showExpCusWrap">
      <label for="showExpFrom">From</label>
      <input type="date" name="showExpFrom" id="showExpFrom">
      <label for="showExpTo">To</label>
      <input type="date" name="showExpTo" id="showExpTo">
      <input type="button" name="showExpCus" id="showExpCus" value="Show" class="exp-button-small">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `line-height` increase or decrease it  , this is to be check through different browsers of course .. *(form elements are also part of the browser not only html tags)*.

```css
.showExpCusWrap {
  background-color: #A8D3FF;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #004F9D;
  padding:  10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.showExpCusWrap label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.showExpCusWrap input[type="date"] {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* increase all
label, input:not([type="button"]) {
line-height:1.4em;
}
*/

label,
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
/* or decrease the one 
[type="button"] {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="showExpCusWrap">
  <label for="showExpFrom">From</label>
  <input type="date" name="showExpFrom" id="showExpFrom">
  <label for="showExpTo">To</label>
  <input type="date" name="showExpTo" id="showExpTo">
  <input type="button" name="showExpCus" id="showExpCus" value="Show" class="exp-button-small">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried setting line-height. This only reduces the height of the button. The spacing from top still exists. I don't understand, even with padding set to 0, why there is a top and bottom spacing for the elements. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @dr_dev it might be different from a browser to another, line-height or font-size could be an option. If you check under FF with the same border-colors, then i do not see much difference. Which browser do you use ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/byzGOo

Answer (score 0):

I have come to this [solution](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/BevVVy). May be this is the solution you are looking for. To your `.showExpCusWrap` class I add these lines of CSS and it's work for me.

```
 /* add the following code*/
  line-height:1;
  font-size:0.9em;
```

As you declare a relative `font-size` with `em` value; So to adjust the height of the inline block I took same amount of height with the help of `line-height:1;`. Here is full code for you.

```css
.showExpCusWrap {
  background-color: #A8D3FF;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #004F9D;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  /* add the following code*/
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.showExpCusWrap label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.showExpCusWrap input[type="date"] {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="showExpCusWrap">
  <label for="showExpFrom">From</label>
  <input type="date" name="showExpFrom" id="showExpFrom">
  <label for="showExpTo">To</label>
  <input type="date" name="showExpTo" id="showExpTo">
  <input type="button" name="showExpCus" id="showExpCus" value="Show" class="exp-button-small">
</div>
```